# Append/Print/Insert Array c++ function issue

Tags: c++, insert, append

> I am having trouble figuring out these functions, I am trying to pass these array as functions to print the array and be able to insert or append numbers in the array. I am getting errors for the for( loops in my functions that say, "suggest parentheses around assignment use as truth value" I don't quite understand what my issue is here.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int MAX = 5;

int Append(int A[], int &numUsed, int num);
void Print(int A[], int &numUsed);
void Init(int A[], int num);
void Insert(int A[], int &numUsed, int num, int position);

int main()
{
    int numUsed=0;

    int oneD[MAX];

    Init(oneD, 0);
    Print(oneD, numUsed);
    Append(oneD, numUsed, 7);
    Insert(oneD, numUsed, num, position);
    return 0;


}
int Append(int A[], int &numUsed, int num){
    if(numUsed>=MAX){
        return 1;
    }
    A[numUsed++]=num;
    return 0;

}
void Print(int A[], int &numUsed){
    for (int i=0; i=numUsed; i++)
        cout<<A[i]<<" ";

}
void Init(int A[], int num){
    for(int i=0; i=MAX; i++){
        A[i]=num;
    }
}
void Insert(int A[], int &numUsed, int num, int position){
    numUsed++;
    A[position]=numUsed;
    position=numUsed-1;
    position--;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Compiler tries to tell you that i = numUsed will set(assign) i to the
value of numUsed and not compare i to numUsed, as you might expect.

Replace

```
i=numUsed
```

in the for-loop with

```
i<numUsed
```

and

```
i=MAX
```

with

```
i<MAX
```

to get the desired result.